# Running command line is not correct in Gradle

Tags: gradle, cmd

Following is my code:

```
task encodeFile(type: Exec) {
    workingDir dirName
    def files = file(dirName).listFiles()
    files.each { File file ->
        if (file.isFile()) {
            println " *** $file.name *** "
            def tmpName = "tmp$file.name"
            println " === $tmpName"
            commandLine "cmd", "/c native2ascii $file.name $tmpName"
            commandLine "cmd", "/c del $file.name"
            commandLine "cmd", "/c move $tmpName $file.name"
//            commandLine "cmd", "/c move $file.name $tmpName"
            println " === $file.name is moved"
            println "----------------------------------"

//            """executable "native2ascii" "$file.name" "$tmpName""""".execute()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to encode all the files under the specified folder for localization. But when I ran the code above, only the last file is changed as expected. I printed some messages and all the files are iterated.

Does anyone know what happens here?

Comment: Yes, the last iteration of `each` invoked on `files` object sets the configuration up and *wins* - you can change the order to verify it. Can `native2ascii` process multiple files at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the last iteration of each invoked on files object sets the configuration up and wins - you can change the order of files passed to verify it.

`native2ascii` task is built-in gradle by default, you can try e.g.:

```
task n2a {
   doLast {
      ant.native2ascii(
         src   : project.file('n2a-src'),
         dest  : project.file('n2a-dest') 
      )
   }
}
```

It seems that there's no need to do it via `Exec` task.

Comment: Thanks, Opal. I'm just not familiar to ant method in Gradle. Now I know it. And for my script above, it's my mistake that iterates the files under the folder when I'm making some changes in this folder.

Comment: @Sky, you can also accept answers (and upvote) to you previous questions if they were answered. Near every question (left side) you have w *tick* with gray border, while clicked it will be filled green. It means the answer is accepted.

Answer (score -1):

For me this is working properly:

```
processResources {
    "*.properties, *.txt".split(",").each {pattern ->
        filesMatching ("**/" + pattern.trim ()) {
            filter {
                it
                    .replace ('${projectVersion}', project.version)
                    .replace ('${projectName}', project.name)
            }
        }
    }

    doLast {
        if (file (processResources.destinationDir).exists()) {
            ant.native2ascii (
                src: "${processResources.destinationDir}",
                dest: "${processResources.destinationDir}/../ascii",
                includes: '**/*.properties',
            )

            copy {
                from "${processResources.destinationDir}/../ascii"
                into processResources.destinationDir
            }
        }
    }
}
```